# Unable to register font programmatically in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to register font programmatically in swift 3. Here is the piece of code i am using to install fonts. The font i am trying to install is [Oswald](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oswald)

```
func installFonts(_ fonts: [String]){
    for i in 0 ..< fonts.count{
        let font = fonts[i].components(separatedBy: ".")
        let fontPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: font[0], withExtension: font[1])!
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        if let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(url: fontPath as CFURL) {
            let font = CGFont(dataProvider)
            if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

None of the fonts get installed and error description states:

`Optional(Swift.Unmanaged<__ObjC.CFError>(_value: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreText.CTFontManagerErrorDomain Code=105 \"Could not register the CGFont \'<CGFont (0x6100000d9f30): Oswald-Bold>\'\" UserInfo={NSDescription=Could not register the CGFont \'<CGFont (0x6100000d9f30): Oswald-Bold>\', CTFailedCGFont=<CGFont (0x6100000d9f30): Oswald-Bold>}))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that your font isn't working.  I tried something very similar and it worked fine.

1. Downloaded a TTF font: http://dl.dafont.com/dl/?f=comicate
2. Dragged into Xcode, added to the target
3. Ran the following code:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       if (installFont("comicate")) {
           print("Font installed")
       }
   }

   @discardableResult
   func installFont(_ font:String) -> Bool {

       guard let fontUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: font, withExtension: "ttf") else {
           return false
       }

       let fontData = try! Data(contentsOf: fontUrl)

       if let provider = CGDataProvider.init(data: fontData as CFData) {

           var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

           let font:CGFont = CGFont(provider)
           if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
               print(error.debugDescription)
               return false
           } else {
               return true
           }
       }
       return false
   }
   ```

   }

I do in fact see "Font installed" printed.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Something is wrong with the Font file - Oswald. The "COMICATE" font installed correctly with my code.

Comment: Why would some fonts not install on iOS? I downloaded them from official Google's website and the files seem to work when i do it via plist.

Comment: Crashes at `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)` for me.

Answer (score 7):

Error code 105 means that the font is already registered (ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfontmanagererror/alreadyregistered)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, and couldn't work out why the font was still appearing correctly in the app despite an error being reported.

Turns out iOS already includes the font I was trying to load! I assume the error was caused because there already existed a font of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the following CoreText functions work. Something to note, is that CoreText supports more than just `ttf` format, it also supports `ttc`, which is also very useful.

```
import CoreText

//: Register with batch of font files
func registerFontResources(_ fonts: [String]) -> Bool {
    let fontURLs: [URL] = fonts.flatMap {
        Bundle.main.url(forResource: $0, withExtension: nil)
    }
    return CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURLs(fontURLs as CFArray, .process, nil)
}

//: Register with single font file
func registerFontResource(_ font: String) -> Bool {
    if let fontURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: font, withExtension: nil) {
        return CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(fontURL as CFURL, .process, nil)
    }
    return false
}
```

Also the 3rd argument to those functions provide a way to receive errors. I did not demonstrate that here because if you only want success value, that's already the return.